# Using DataInputStream after BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, datainputstream, pgm

A sample binary PGM file is as follows:

```
P5
# This is a comment
10 10
255
#image intensity information in bytes that I am unable to copy paste here
```

like

[image]

When I try to read the file using the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pgm_reader2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 4){
                System.out.println(dis.readLine());
                i++;
            }
            while(dis.available() != 0){
                System.out.print(dis.readUnsignedByte() + " ");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly and gives the following output:

```
P5
# This is a comment
10 10
255
0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0
```

but it shows that the `DataInputStream.readLine()` method is deprecated. So to avoid using this method I tried using the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method, as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pgm_reader2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inRaw));
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 4){
                System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
                i++;
            }
            while(dis.available() != 0){
                System.out.print(dis.readUnsignedByte() + " ");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output changed to:

```
P5
# This is a comment
10 10
255
```

and it seems that the second `while` loop i.e.

```
while(dis.available() != 0){
    System.out.print(dis.readUnsignedByte() + " ");
}
```

is not working.

What could be the possible reason for this?

I tried using a larger image i.e. 400x400 image instead of 10x10 image, 
[image]

and tried to copy the bytes from one image and paste them into the new file using the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pgm_reader2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
            FileOutputStream outRaw = new FileOutputStream("B_test.pgm");
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outRaw);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inRaw));
            String line = null;
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 4){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                dos.writeBytes(line);
                dos.writeBytes("\n");
                i++;
            }
            int intbyte = 0;
            while(dis.available() != 0){
                intbyte = dis.readUnsignedByte();
                dos.writeByte(intbyte);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the output image came out like this:

[image]

If I use `DataInputStream.readLine()` in the whole code then the output image comes exactly the same as the input image. How is it happening?

Comment: Couldn't you usse `DataInputStream#readUTF()`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I tried using it just now and it gives `java.io.EOFException` exception

Comment: didnt you say you want to use buffered reader? then why mix the two??

Comment: @gpasch because I have to read the binary data too

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568616/reading-strings-and-binary-from-the-same-fileinputstream

Comment: thats a mess that you are doing -I dont care if its deprecated or what just use one

Comment: @Meiko thanks for the link, it probably is because the buffererReader is consuming everything.

Comment: @gpasch in this case there is a reason, why you should not use it: `@deprecated This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BufferedReader is buffered which means it will read as much as possible (up the the buffer's size) to minimise the number of calls to the underlying Reader or Stream. As such it is not suitable for changing the stream later. In general it is bad idea to change the wrapper of an underlying stream or reader unless you really know what you are doing.

In this case, the simplest solution is to use the deprecated method.  You could write your own replacement for readLine() but that might just introduce more problems than it helps.

> @deprecated This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.

This is true, however for ASCII characters it will probably do what you need.

Comment: I tested the code for larger input file and have edited the question to include the results, can you please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to why the image is shifted a bit upwards and leftwards and why there is black strip at the bottom when I use `bufferedReader` before `dataInputStream`. Explaination:

we had 160000 bytes to read after header if the image size was 400*400. Since bufferedReader reads extra and keep in its buffer, lets assume that it 25000 bytes extra after the header. So when the `dataInputStream` starts to read the image intensities, it gets to read from the 25001th byte. And it puts the 2500001th byte at 1st position, and therefore all the pixel intensities are shifted 250000 position behind i.e. 62 rows up and 200 pixels left. Since there are 25000 bytes less in the last so 0 is written from pixel (160000-25000+1) to 160000, hence the black strip at the bottom.